# Where all project structures supported by tomcat/jboss are described?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea, jboss, war

Where I can read which project structure is supported by different web servers? Are they all the same for all web servers. Is this a standard? Why eclipse and idea have different folders for the content i.e WebContent and webapp? Also why maven have different structure.. Can I make one simple war file without and IDE but just by hand - just with 7zip or winrar for example?

Comment: You can easily google for your answer. This community is for code problems. If you have any deployment or code problem then let us know where you stuck but for such questions please read their documentations

Comment: I google it and didn't find anything. I thought the community is for programming problems and concepts not only for code. I want to know what exactly is web project, concept of the web project structure and who make these standards. Can I make a war just with zipping files (with compression or without ) with winrar and rename the file to .war?

Comment: Sorry but this is not academy or teaching centre where we can build your concepts.

Comment: ??. I not understand